# How can I set a CNAME record when my domain provider only support A and AAAA record?

Tags: dns, ip-address, cname, dynamic-dns, static-ip

My domain extension (`.at.tw`) is a testing project, and it **only supports** 5  `A` or `AAAA` records, and not `NS`, `CNAME` or other types you might found in normal DNS.

I want to use [Ghost's](https://ghost.io) paid hosting (so not self-hosting) which requires pointing a CNAME record since they're not using static IP (which IP will change time by time). But as you see, unfortunately my domain doesn't support it, so I am trying to find a solution to solve this.

I've tried [No-IP](http://www.noip.com) which supports pointing to a CNAME record (I found them since they're mainly providing service for connecting to your computer remotely), but their service also needs to point the nameservers to them in order to use.

I have ask my hosting friend: they tell me you can not point an `A` record to a DNS service first then point it to another record (something like forwarding)

With this situation, how can I point my domain to a `CNAME` record or non-static IP?

Comment: They don't support NS records?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller As their instruction and what their support said (in Chinese), they launched the domain extension .at.tw this year as personal domain and this project is a testing stage project which will be free to register one per email this year (2018). And the project will whether terminated or continues depending on the condition in the end of the year.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That happens. When `.TEL` started, due to its specific services done by registry you were not able to choose your nameservers all domain names were using nameservers controlled by the registry.

Comment: Will is this only for a website or will there be other services? Also, even if you find a solution for this case, and since you specifically say it is a temporary things that may get shutdown later is it wise to try to circumvent its constraints, as you are trying to push a round square into a square hole? In other words can't you just use any other domain name or any other hosting provider that fits the case you are in? That would be far simpler...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Actually since its newly launched so lucky I can get my first name matched (Andrew), also there's only a possibility to be shut down while I believe it isn't a high possibility. Also it's a website, I'm using Ghost's hosting service which can add custom domain by point CNAME to site-name.ghost.io

Comment: There are almost 2000 TLDs nowadays and you should not feel too much sentimentaly attached to a domain name. As Esa Jokinen replied while you theoretically could find a solution sort of working, it will be a lot of time and energy spent where changing the hosting provider or the TLD is a no brainer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably chosen two services that simply aren't compatible with their conflicting requirements. You must abandon one of the two or arrange something between them e.g.

1. `example.at.tw. A` to a static IP from another hosting.
2. Reverse proxy from `example.at.tw.` to `www.example.com.`
3. `www.example.com. CNAME` to Ghost's hosting.

Naturally choosing either different TLD or different hosting would be easy, straightforward and less expensive compared to this.

Answer (score 0):

Point your nameserver to no-ip (or anywhere else) and set up the A record and CNAME record to point to your web site and the MX record to point to your email host.  Depending on which other DNS records you need you can set them up as well.

DNS can be hosted anywhere, you are most definitely not stuck with where you bought the domain.

Comment: What did I missed in my question? I've said, due to my domain extension is a testing project it doesn't supports nameserver

Comment: OK @Munucial I didn't realise you meant that that is ALL the domain extension supports.  I thought it was a DNS hosting problem.  I will leave the answer though as it might help others with DNS problems.